# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem'

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

Hi there i have define more than one tabItem in my TabControl. tabItem1, tabItem2, tabItem3

these are CloseableTabItem.

if i add a node in tabItem1 and press a button to make a subGraph model for this node. the

same node should be appear in tabItem2 so that tabItem2-Header = nodeName and nodeName =

tabItem1-Header.

Without (TabItem)tabControl.SelectedContent == tabItem1, the code work correct but the

Problem ist if i added a new node in tabItem2 and press the subGraph-Button node will be

added to tabItem3 but the nodeName = tabItem1-Header.

my Code throw an Exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem'."

```
MyNodeData todata = new MyNodeData();
if (tabItem1.IsLoaded && (TabItem)tabControl.SelectedContent == tabItem1)
{
  string childNodeName = (String)tabItem1.Header;
  todata.Text = childNodeName;
  return;
}
 if (tabItem2.IsLoaded)
{
  string childNodeName = (String)tabItem2.Header;
  todata.Text = childNodeName;
  return;
}
 if (tabItem3.IsLoaded)
{
  string childNodeName = (String)tabItem3.Header;
  todata.Text = childNodeName;
  return;
}
```

Comment: The meaning of the error is fairly clear: `tabControl.SelectedContent` is a `Grid`, not a `TabItem`.  What's your question?

Comment: Looks like your SelectedContent is a Grid rather than a TabItem.....

Comment: Is this really your code? TabControl does not have a SelectedContent member according to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx

Comment: @Kek: Right. This `CloseableTabItem` I am using in my WPF App also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectedContent` is the content of the TabItem. What you want is `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Not SelectedItem but SelectedTab

Comment: @RamanZhylich No, SelectedTab is for Windows Forms. This is WPF.

Comment: +1: Agree. Sorry, there was no anything about WPF in the text of the article except tag.